# Server side scripting onkeyup PHP

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, onkeyup

i am trying to make an search box which search the name from elastic search database, but when i run the it always give me an error that ----

**Notice: Undefined index: value in the line --> $query = $_GET['search_keyword'];**

but from my script i believe it should get the "search_keyword".

**Search box --**

```
<form method="GET" action="/latest/helloTestData">

    <input type="text" name="sample_search" id="sample_search" onkeyup="search_func(this.value);">

</form>
```

Script --

```
    <script>
       $(function () {
    var minlength = 3;

    $("#sample_search").keyup(function () {
        var that = this,
        value = $(this).val();

        if (value.length >= minlength ) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/latest/helloTestData", // address to the php function
                data: {
                    'search_keyword' : value
                },
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(msg){
                    //we need to check if the value is the same
                    if (value==$(that).val()) {
                    //Receiving the result of search here
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}); 
    </script>
```

**PHP ---**

```
public function helloTestDataAction() {

        $paramss = array('hosts' => array('localhost:9200'));
        $client = new Elasticsearch\Client($paramss); 

        $query = $_GET['search_keyword'];
        if ($query != "") {

        $params = array();
        $params['size'] = 1000000000;
        $params['index'] = 'myindex';
        $params['type'] = 'mytype';
        $params['body']['query']['bool']['must'] = array(
            array('match' => array('name' => $query)), // search data by input data
        );

        $esresult = $client->search($params);

            if ($esresult < 1) {
                echo "Your search did not match any documents. Please try different keywords.";
            } else {
                                echo $esresult; //results found here and display them
            }
            }

             return new Response('ok');
    }
```

Can anyone knows how to fix this problem. Thanks a lot in advanced.

Comment: Try with `$_GET['search_keyword'];`

Comment: Exactly, you have'nt `'value'` in get request, you have `'search_keyword' `only.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: search_keyword

Comment: why are you using jQuery keyup function AND assigning to the form the keyup event? What is search_func?

Comment: I believe I see a syntax error on your `$paramss` definition

Comment: Yup, there's an extra comma after your array containing localhost:9200

Comment: @DonCallisto you are right but it does not change anything

Answer (score 1):

Modifiy `$_GET['value']` into `$_GET['search_keyword']`

So

```
public function helloTestDataAction() {
    [...]
    $_GET['search_keyword'];
    [...]
}
```

You're searching for a key that will not be into `$_GET` array, as, into your ajax request, you're passing a key named `search_keyword` and so this is the error

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: search_keyword

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace

```
 $_GET['value'] to $_GET['search_keyword']
```

Comment: Exactly, what your answer add to mine and to comments?

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: search_keyword

Answer (score 0):

Quick and simple! The front-end pass the typed text via GET by url.

In this test I put the 2 files in the same folder. Change as you need.

Front-end:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<div id="my_header" style="background-color:lightblue">
</div>

<input type="text" id="foo" value="bar" onkeyup="loadlink(this)" />

<script>
function loadlink(e){
    $('#my_header').load('back.php?var='+e.value,function () {
         $(this).unwrap();
    });
}
</script>
```

Back-end (back.php):

```
<?php 
echo "received: " . $_GET["var"] . ' <br>at ' . gmdate('Y-m-d h:i:s \G\M\T', time());
?>
```